# Highcharts Scatter plot 3d

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I want to connect all the points in 3d scatter plot using Highcharts.Can anyone please let me know whether this is possible or not?

I referred to this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-scatter-3d-rncytq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scatter3d.lineWidth` option, to add a line between the markers.

```
plotOptions: {
  scatter3d: {
    lineWidth: 2,
  },
},
```

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter3d.lineWidth

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-scatter-3d-nkp1zo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

---

**EDIT:**

Angular draggable Scatter 3d demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-forked-ojp8bj

Comment: Hello Magdalena, can you please send a demo of drag and rotate of 3d scatter plot in hinghcharts angular plus when I click on the points in scatter plot, it should show information about the graph. Thank you

Comment: Hi, here you are https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-forked-tsljn5 . To detect information about the graph, you need to add the `point.click` event - as in the demo.  API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events.click